# Uploading an image to Azure Blob Storage using React

Tags: reactjs, azure-blob-storage

I want to upload an image to Azure Blob Storage using React.

I've tried a lot of examples and none of them work.

The one that seemed the best was [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-javascript-client-libraries) but still didn't manage to get it working on React.

What I'm trying right now is to use the createContainerIfNotExists method just to test and the error is `Cannot read property createBlobServiceWithSas of undefined`

My code is the following:

```
import AzureStorage from 'azure-storage';

const account = {
  name: 'x',
  sas: 'x',
};

const blobUri = `https://${account.name}.blob.core.windows.net`;
const blobService = AzureStorage.Blob.createBlobServiceWithSas(blobUri, account.sas);

export const createContainer = () => {
  blobService.createContainerIfNotExists('test', (error, container) => {
    if (error) {
      // Handle create container error
    } else {
      console.log(container.name);
    }
  });
};

export default createContainer;
```

Comment: Could you please tell me your error message?

Comment: Besides, could you please provide your test code?

Comment: @JimXu edited the post to show my actual code

Comment: have you added ```<script src="scripts/azure-storage.blob.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>``` in your html page?

Comment: no, installed ´azure-storage´ npm package instead because I'm using React

Comment: Could you please which version sdk you use? V2 or V10?

Comment: my node version is 10.14.1

Comment: OK. Could you please try to use ```AzureStorage.createBlobServiceWithSas(blobUri, account.sas);``` to create blobservice?

Comment: @JimXu The error doesn't pop now but the method doesn't create the container

Comment: You also can use the code ```blobService.createContainerIfNotExists('test', (error, container) =>``` to create container. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs#create-a-container

Comment: the method `createContainerIfNotExists` works but I can't use the method `createBlockBlobFromBrowserFile`

Comment: could you please tell me the error message?

Comment: fs.stat is not a function

Comment: Could you please tell me the version of Azure storage your use or the command you use to install azure storage sdk?

Comment: v2.10.3 npm install azure-storage

Comment: According to my research,[Azure storage V2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node#azure-storage-javascript-client-library-for-browsers)  only supports browser usage with classic single JS bundle file. So you need to refer to the js file. If you still just use the sdk, I suggest you use Azure storage SDK v10. For more details, please refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/storage#compatibility and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56514478/upload-blockblob-to-azure-storage-using-react.

Comment: Is that Ok for you?

Comment: I assumed that I can't do it with React and it is just possible to do it in a separate backend with node or C#. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, because you develop A React application, we can not use the `createBlockBlobFromBrowserFile` method. We just can use the method in the browser. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-storage/azurestorage.services.blob.blobservice.blobservice?view=azure-node-latest).
[image]

According to the situation, I suggest you use the other method(such as `uploadStreamToBlockBlob`) to upload image with V10 sdk. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/?view=azure-node-latest