# managing azure blob using react-native

Tags: azure, react-native, azure-blob-storage

I want to update images on the azure blob storage . I downloaded `@azure/storage-blob` and `@azure/identity` even after all these downloads I am getting errors and after this  i downloaded `@azure/logger` it showed an error

> "exit with node 1"

The code is as below.

```
var AzureStorage = require('azure-storage'); 
const account = { name: "x", sas:"x" }; 
var blobUri = 'https://' + account.name + '.blob.core.windows.net'; 
var blobService = AzureStorage.Blob.createBlobServiceWithSas(blobUri, account.sas); 
console.log(azureinformation); 
console.log(AzureStorage); 
blobService.createBlockBlobFromBrowserFile('aic', "task1", data.sampleImgData, function(error, result, response) { 
    finishedOrError = true; 
    if (error) {
        console.log(success);
    } 
});
```

I am using .61 version of react native. please let me know the solution if you have . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question and include any code that you have written.

Comment: var AzureStorage = require('azure-storage');
 const account = {
  name: "x",
  sas:"x"
 };
 var blobUri = 'https://' + account.name + '.blob.core.windows.net';
 var blobService = AzureStorage.Blob.createBlobServiceWithSas(blobUri, account.sas);
 console.log(`azureinformation`);
 console.log(AzureStorage);
 blobService.createBlockBlobFromBrowserFile('aic', "task1", data.sampleImgData, function(error, result, response) {
  finishedOrError = true;
  if (error) {console.log(`success`)} });

Comment: @AnirudhKhatwani Could you tell me if you want to use Azure blob storage sdk in node.js runtime? If so, we can not use the ```createBlockBlobFromBrowserFile``` method. It only supports in the Browsers. For more details, please refer to http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/BlobService.html#createBlockBlobFromBrowserFile__anchor

Comment: hi jim thanks for the reply i have the solution of managing azure blob using node js but i wanted to manage blob using react native.

Answer (score 0):

There is some mistakes in your description and code, as below.

1. The latest version is `@azure/storage-blob` (its version >= 10), but it does not include the function `createBlockBlobFromBrowserFile` which be belong to V2 SDK. There is a similar SO thread [Upload BlockBlob to Azure Storage using React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56514478/upload-blockblob-to-azure-storage-using-react/56520060#56520060) which you can refer to.
2. Your current code seems to be from the sample [`Azure Storage JavaScript Client Library Sample for Blob Operations`](https://dmrelease.blob.core.windows.net/azurestoragejssample/samples/sample-blob.html), but you should get the variable `AzureStorage` via the code `<script src="azure-storage.blob.js"></script>` in HTML page, not `var AzureStorage = require('azure-storage');` for Node server.
3. If you want to use the latest SDK `@azure/storage-blob` in browser, please see the sample code https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/storage/storage-blob/samples/browserSamples/largeFileUploads.js.

So first of all, you should choose a SDK version as a solution for your current needs.

Answer (score 0):

i have uploaded image on azure blob using the enlisted code . i used image picker to get the image and after that

{

```
let blobUri = `https://containername.blob.core.windows.net`;
let sas = "genrate sas token from storage account and give expire limit of 1 year";
let resposne = RNFetchBlob.fetch('PUT', `${blobUri}/aic/${data.sampleImgData.uri.fileName}?${sas}`, {
  'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob',
  'content-type': 'application/octet-stream',
  'x-ms-blob-content-type': data.sampleImgData.uri.type,
}, data.sampleImgData.uri.data);
resposne.then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err));
console.log(`${blobUri}/aic/${data.sampleImgData.uri.fileName}`);
azureimageurl = `${blobUri}/aic/${data.sampleImgData.uri.fileName}`;
```

}