# SharedKeyCredential is not a constructor. Azure-storage react app

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to use the following code to upload a blockblob to Azure-Storage in a react app. However, I'm getting the following error.

> TypeError: SharedKeyCredential is not a constructor

Any ideas?

@azure/storage-blob@10.3.0

```
import React from 'react';

const {
  Aborter,
  BlobURL,
  BlockBlobURL,
  ContainerURL,
  ServiceURL,
  StorageURL,
  SharedKeyCredential,
  AnonymousCredential,
  TokenCredential
} = require("@azure/storage-blob"); // Change to "@azure/storage-blob" in your package

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <button onClick={onClicked()} />

    </div>
  );

  async function onClicked() {

    // Enter your storage account name and shared key
    const account = "REMOVED_MY_ACCOUNT";
    const accountKey = "REMOVED_ACCOUNT_KEY";

    // Use SharedKeyCredential with storage account and account key
    const sharedKeyCredential = new SharedKeyCredential(account, accountKey);

    // Use TokenCredential with OAuth token
    const tokenCredential = new TokenCredential("token");
    tokenCredential.token = "renewedToken"; // Renew the token by updating token field of token credential

    // Use AnonymousCredential when url already includes a SAS signature
    const anonymousCredential = new AnonymousCredential();

    // Use sharedKeyCredential, tokenCredential or anonymousCredential to create a pipeline
    const pipeline = StorageURL.newPipeline(sharedKeyCredential);

    // List containers
    const serviceURL = new ServiceURL(
      // When using AnonymousCredential, following url should include a valid SAS or support public access
      `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`,
      pipeline
    );

    // Create a container
    const containerName = `newcontainer${new Date().getTime()}`;
    const containerURL = ContainerURL.fromServiceURL(serviceURL, containerName);

    const createContainerResponse = await containerURL.create(Aborter.none);
    console.log(
      `Create container ${containerName} successfully`,
      createContainerResponse.requestId
    );

    // Create a blob
    const content = "hello";
    const blobName = "newblob" + new Date().getTime();
    const blobURL = BlobURL.fromContainerURL(containerURL, blobName);
    const blockBlobURL = BlockBlobURL.fromBlobURL(blobURL);
    const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobURL.upload(
      Aborter.none,
      content,
      content.length
    );
    console.log(
      `Upload block blob ${blobName} successfully`,
      uploadBlobResponse.requestId
    );

  }
}

export default App;
```

Edit:
I was calling the wrong API. You can create a new Visual Studio project that uses the .Net/React template. This was the code example I was looking for.

Comment: Are you aware that if it does work, the storage admin key is available publicly in your app? Typically you'd use shared access tokens generated by a back-end service to access blob storage from a front-end.

Comment: Yes. I follow what you are saying, but I may still be struggling to fully understand how to work around it.

Comment: Well, there are really two options: a) make the blob container public or b) generate a temporary SAS token in a back-end and use that. There should be a sample how to do b in the language of your choice.

Comment: Thanks @juunas, I understand what you are saying. I'm trying to walk through the example of this at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55613356/how-to-upload-folder-into-azure-automatically/55626953#55626953

Comment: @juunas I think you should post your option (b) as an answer. I don't think option (a) would work as upload operation would always need to be authorized (using Shared Key, SAS or AD Token). Option (a) would work for reads as anonymous reads are allowed by setting container ACL as either Blob or Public.

Comment: It would be really helpful just to have one code file with the E2E example. Started hitting import errors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm the developer of storage JS SDK. `SharedKeyCredential` is only available in Node.js runtime. For browsers, for security concerns, please use Shared Access Signature (SAS) or OAuth Token for your authentications.

Comment: Yes. This was my issue. I was not calling the correct Azure-Storage SDK v10 API. When you're on the browser, you NEED to use a SAS. Any other authentication API is not found.

Comment: @Xiaoning Liu  I'm facing the same issue in my NodeJs application

Comment: Is there any way for this to work from an Electron app?